# Why won't Windows 8.1 install update KB2919355

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

I have a custom built PC running Windows 8.1 64-bit but it won't install update KB2919355

I've tried lots of solutions including reinstalling Windows 8.1, running DSM commands in cmd and everything but it always fails!

Any ideas on why it will not install?

Comment: what error code are you getting? Also what verion/bit verion of windows are you running?

Comment: @NabilAziz error code 8007371

Comment: share the folder **C:\Windows\logs\CBS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But of a weird resolution.

I had originally been using an unattended Windows 8.1 disk I created using NTLite software.

Since reinstalling with the official Windows 8.1 disk (unedited) I haven't had the problem since!

So yeah, use the retail Windows 8.1 disk and don't modify it!

Answer (score 0):

That specific error code wasn't deplyed correctly, it caused alot of error with windows users, but with the Error code 8007371 you can try the following solutions.

Enter command prompt in the search box.

In the list of results, swipe down on or right-click Command Prompt, and then tap or click Run as administrator.

In the Administrator: Command Prompt window, enter the following commands. Press the Enter key after each command.

If you're running a 64-bit version of Windows 8.1, type:

```
dism /online /remove-package /packagename:Package_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.14
```

If you're running a 32-bit version of Windows 8.1, type:

```
dism /online /remove-package /packagename:Package_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.1.14
```

If you're running Windows RT 8.1, type:

```
dism /online /remove-package /packagename:Package_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~arm~~6.3.1.14
```

OR

Type the following command, and then press Enter:

```
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

OR

Type the following command, and then press Enter:

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup
```

or you can download the actual update from the support site

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42335 - 64bit

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42327 - 32bit